# Generating PHP pages from an asp.net MVC application

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3

We have an MVC 3 application that we use internally, and we need to generate a set of static web pages for our external website using our business data. Our external site is running Drupal, so we would like to use PHP templates to render the pages. That way our web designers can make cosmetic changes to the pages by editing the templates without learning a new templating language.

Is there a PHP library we could call to generate the pages? We don't want to run a PHP server, and certainly not a Drupal server.

Comment: You mean Razor is hard to understand?! Your designers should not have a problem with it.

Comment: It isn't, but it adds friction. Also, at some point we might migrate views of our data to their server so they can then generate the pages from the PHP pages without changing anything.  Very political...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a PHP module for IIS so you could render php templates with it

[PHP module for IIS](http://php.iis.net/)

for the template system you could use smarty or build your own to make the easiest for your designers. building your own template system is not complicated and you'll get better performance.

hope this helps